# $index of element changes while using filter how to get correct index of element angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I am using filter the index of the element is changing when i delete an element it is deleting another element how to get the exact $index of the element?

```
 <div class="repeater" ng-repeat="student in students | filter : query">
 <button type="button" class="close pull-right" ng-click="remove($index)">&times;</button>
 $scope.remove = function(id){
     $scope.students.splice(id,1);
 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use the student object itself.

```
<button type="button" class="close pull-right" ng-click="remove(student)">&times;</button>



$scope.remove = function(student){
     $scope.students.splice($scope.students.indexOf(student),1);
 };
```